# Arch Linux: Private Internet Access VPN no internet traffic when connected

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, vpn

Problem: I can connect to PIA servers, but when connected, no websites resolve. The instant I disconnect from the VPN, any website will load normally.

My situation: 5.8.8-arch1-1. I use the network manager, but I've also got the PIA client. Neither work. I *have* tried manually added PIA's DNS servers in the network manager and in their client (so please don't just paste a link to the arch wiki). My subscription is active because I can access the web with PIA via other OS's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are log files you could read, like /var/log/messages and or /var/log/syslog, or the kernel ring buffer with 'dmesg'. It sounds like your DNS setup is borked. When the system tries to get an IP, it can't, because it's not configured to reach a DNS server when VPN is connected. There is no automatic way to fix this.

This usually doesn't happen anymore. But if you have PIA configured in network-manager (NM), and you're using the PIA desktop client, that could do it. You want to use PIA's DNS servers. So, make sure that's checked in PIA client's 'settings'.

Look in nm and remove any PIA VPNs. Shut them down first. Get the latest PIA client and install it. Have a look at 'iptables -L'. Is DNS blocked? Reboot. Look in '/etc/resolve.conf'. Anything interesting? There is another 'resolve.conf' virtual file in /var. Check that one too. But you might need to use 'find' to find it. The one in /var is actually a socket, not a disk file.

If Internet problem is solved somewhere along the way, you don't need to finish with everything in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed response. I just updated the client and that fixed everything, so no worries. I'm curious what I should have been looking for. I didn't have a /var/log/messages nor /var/log/syslog file.

pre-update: `dmesg` gave the following (starting from where startup messages about bluetooth adapters and soundscards end):

```
[   19.382223] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.289468] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   22.012225] wlp115s0: authenticate with 04:d9:f5:2b:4f:a8
[   22.017983] wlp115s0: send auth to 04:d9:f5:2b:4f:a8 (try 1/3)
[   22.049891] wlp115s0: authenticated
[   22.050545] wlp115s0: associate with 04:d9:f5:2b:4f:a8 (try 1/3)
[   22.052708] wlp115s0: RX AssocResp from 04:d9:f5:2b:4f:a8 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=5)
[   22.062585] wlp115s0: associated
[   22.089777] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp115s0: link becomes ready
[   22.152999] wlp115s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 04:d9:f5:2b:4f:a8
[   28.880556] kauditd_printk_skb: 14 callbacks suppressed
[   28.880557] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680230.347:286): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user@969 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   28.888291] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680230.357:287): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@969 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   32.025383] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680233.493:288): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   50.337876] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680251.807:289): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   50.600663] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680252.070:290): prog-id=10 op=UNLOAD
[   50.600667] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680252.070:291): prog-id=9 op=UNLOAD
[   50.952688] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680252.420:292): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-localed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   51.200918] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680252.670:293): prog-id=16 op=UNLOAD
[   51.200926] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680252.670:294): prog-id=15 op=UNLOAD
[   80.021647] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680281.490:295): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=geoclue comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  101.104781] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680302.573:296): prog-id=17 op=LOAD
[  101.104813] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680302.573:297): prog-id=18 op=LOAD
[  101.344804] audit: type=1130 audit(1600680302.813:298): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-timedated comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  106.863153] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.330:299): table=filter family=2 entries=109 op=replace pid=3480 comm="iptables"
[  106.867682] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.337:300): table=filter family=10 entries=93 op=replace pid=3483 comm="ip6tables"
[  106.886807] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.353:301): table=filter family=10 entries=94 op=replace pid=3494 comm="ip6tables"
[  106.902780] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.370:302): table=filter family=2 entries=110 op=replace pid=3503 comm="iptables"
[  106.907625] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.377:303): table=filter family=10 entries=95 op=replace pid=3506 comm="ip6tables"
[  106.931056] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.400:304): table=filter family=2 entries=111 op=replace pid=3519 comm="iptables"
[  106.935530] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.403:305): table=filter family=10 entries=96 op=replace pid=3522 comm="ip6tables"
[  106.955612] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.423:306): table=filter family=2 entries=110 op=replace pid=3533 comm="iptables"
[  106.960281] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.427:307): table=filter family=10 entries=95 op=replace pid=3536 comm="ip6tables"
[  106.964264] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680308.433:308): table=filter family=2 entries=111 op=replace pid=3539 comm="iptables"
[  113.410094] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[  113.433268] kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
[  113.433271] audit: type=1130 audit(1600680314.900:310): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  113.542142] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.010:311): table=filter family=2 entries=112 op=replace pid=3663 comm="iptables"
[  113.545886] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.013:312): table=filter family=10 entries=97 op=replace pid=3666 comm="ip6tables"
[  113.549615] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.017:313): table=filter family=2 entries=113 op=replace pid=3669 comm="iptables"
[  113.553411] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.020:314): table=filter family=10 entries=98 op=replace pid=3672 comm="ip6tables"
[  113.560479] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.027:315): table=filter family=2 entries=114 op=replace pid=3677 comm="iptables"
[  113.564174] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.033:316): table=filter family=10 entries=99 op=replace pid=3680 comm="ip6tables"
[  113.583354] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.050:317): table=filter family=2 entries=115 op=replace pid=3693 comm="iptables"
[  113.587070] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.053:318): table=filter family=10 entries=100 op=replace pid=3696 comm="ip6tables"
[  113.591050] audit: type=1325 audit(1600680315.060:319): table=filter family=2 entries=116 op=replace pid=3699 comm="iptables"
[  124.029311] kauditd_printk_skb: 20 callbacks suppressed
[  124.029317] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680325.497:340): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  131.383196] audit: type=1131 audit(1600680332.850:341): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-timedated comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  131.402462] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680332.870:342): prog-id=18 op=UNLOAD
[  131.402464] audit: type=1334 audit(1600680332.870:343): prog-id=17 op=UNLOAD
```

and `iptables -L` gives (post-update, sorry forgot to export this one before the update):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.anchors  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain piavpn.000.allowLoopback (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain piavpn.100.blockAll (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain piavpn.100.protectLoopback (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain piavpn.200.allowVPN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.290.allowDHCP (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255      udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps

Chain piavpn.300.allowLAN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             169.254.0.0/16      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255     

Chain piavpn.305.allowSubnets (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.310.blockDNS (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain piavpn.320.allowDNS (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             cgroup 1384 udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             cgroup 1383 udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             cgroup 1384 tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             cgroup 1383 tcp dpt:domain

Chain piavpn.340.blockVpnOnly (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             cgroup 1384 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain piavpn.350.allowHnsd (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.350.cgAllowHnsd (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match piahnsd cgroup 1384 multiport dports domain,13038
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match piahnsd cgroup 1384 multiport dports domain,13038
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match piahnsd reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain piavpn.390.allowWg (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x3213

Chain piavpn.400.allowPIA (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match piavpn

Chain piavpn.FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.a.100.protectLoopback  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain piavpn.a.000.allowLoopback (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.100.blockAll (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.100.protectLoopback (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.100.protectLoopback  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain piavpn.a.200.allowVPN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.290.allowDHCP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.300.allowLAN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.305.allowSubnets (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.310.blockDNS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.320.allowDNS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.340.blockVpnOnly (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.340.blockVpnOnly  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain piavpn.a.350.allowHnsd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.350.cgAllowHnsd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.390.allowWg (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.a.400.allowPIA (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain piavpn.anchors (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
piavpn.a.000.allowLoopback  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.400.allowPIA  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.390.allowWg  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.350.allowHnsd  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.350.cgAllowHnsd  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.340.blockVpnOnly  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.320.allowDNS  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.310.blockDNS  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.305.allowSubnets  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.300.allowLAN  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.290.allowDHCP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.200.allowVPN  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
piavpn.a.100.blockAll  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` gives:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.192.111
nameserver 192.168.192.1
nameserver 198.162.192.111
```

.111 is my pi-hole DNS lookup server and .1 is my router. Dunno why the .111 is in there twice.

Also interestingly - the network manager still doesn't work, but the client does...May have something to do with switching to their new wireguard protocol from OpenVPN?